# OpenCV processing with a web application

Tags: c++, opencv, web-applications

I am planning on creating a web application that uses OpenCV for image processing. The image processing would be comparing a user uploaded picture with pictures I would have in a database. I would rather the user upload an image instead a similar upload method to [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0ZDQ7ZH76i0) instead via a webcam.

I would like to know how can I do the processing using the OpenCV library? And what would I need to be able to connect my OpenCV processing to my web application?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load image  from web use [VideoCapture](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture) class  open image as we open video file. See the example below.

```
VideoCapture cap;
if(!cap.open("http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/_downloads/opencv-logo.png")){
 cout<<"Cannot open image"<<endl;
 return -1;
 }

Mat src;
cap>>src;
imshow("src",src);
imwrite("image.jpg",src);
waitKey();
```

Or use  [Portable Native Client](http://blog.chromium.org/2013/11/portable-native-client-pinnacle-of.html)  as OpenCV now ported to Google Chrome NaCl and PNaCl, See [OpenCV news](http://opencv.org/opencv-ported-to-google-chrome-nacl-and-pnacl.html) more details

Comment: I have never heard of the Native Client but I will read up on it and hopefully get back to you with more specific enquires I may have about it.

Answer (score 0):

You could take the webcam shots and upload them, and then compare them like traditional image files (from the filesystem and/or database).

A modern way of taking the shots would be to use WebRTC:
http://css.dzone.com/articles/face-detection-using-html5

Other alternatives will probably involve Macromedia Flash or similar stuff.

Comment: That application is a lot more complex than what I wanted to do, but what you said in the first point seems more towards what I would like to do. The question is how can I send the image to my OpenCV application from the webpage? Currently I have to type the image source in my terminal to do the comparison.

Comment: You need a webserver and some script to run on the server (a PHP script for example). Then you setup an HTML page with a simple upload form, this POSTs the data to your script, your script checks the file type and if it's correct, it gets stored on the server filesystem.
You can store the file path somewhere (a database, or even a plain text file) and then simply run your program/executable that does the image processing against that path.

Checkout PHP, and a simple database system.

Comment: Right, this all makes sense the only thing I don't fully understand how can I make the program or executable run? I can upload and store images on the server filesystem somewhere but after storing it how can I run an executable?

Comment: Also in regards to the above, I would need to send data back from the executable to the site.